# What is the difference between executing a command with sudo vs doing so as root user?

Tags: command-line, sudo, root

Im fairly new to linux, and until now, always thought `sudo <command>` was the same as exectuing `<command>` as `root`.
I recently played around a bit with the `ls` command, and noticed a slight, but confusing difference.

When executing `sudo ls -lap` (in the root directory), i get the following output:

[image: sudo ls -lap]

vs. when i execute `ls -lap` as `root` (or as a regular user **without** `sudo`):

[image: ls -lap]

Apart from the obvious but not important color difference, if you actually look closer, you see that the `-p` option (showing a `/` after directories) didn't work on `links` when executing the command with `sudo`.

Is there an actual difference between the two? Or is that a bug?
And either way, doesnt that mean that both commands are processed differently?

Comment: Look at this: `sudo echo $USER`.

Comment: @Pierre that doesn’t show anything useful, because `$USER` is expanded by the current shell, not the shell started by `sudo`.

Comment: @StephenKitt but for interactive cases, that's often a difference affecting the use of sudo, and requiring some tricks like piping a tee command.

Comment: @A.B yes, I understand the difference that Pierre is trying to illustrate, but the example command doesn’t show it.

Comment: Stephen: I agree, I gave bad example.

Comment: Questions such as this have been answered many times here. The "long and short of it", though, is that sudo does _not_ launch a shell with the root users' configurations files, such as `/root/.bashrc`. Thus, commonly configured environment variables, such as output options for `ls` or the value of the `PATH` variable are not generally modified when `sudo` executes the command.  (I believe, but not certain, that `sudo` does do some housecleaning for safety and security, however.) When you launch a root shell, root's configuration/environment gets loaded and used normally.

Comment: @C.M. in this particular case it’s not even environment variables.

Comment: (Read `man sudo` for the _full_ details,  and some of the more technically accurate detail than I can provide in a short comment space.)

Comment: That thing about adding the `/` to symlink targets might depend on the version of `ls`. With ls from GNU coreutils 8.30, `-p` seems to never add it. `-F` does, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ls` is an alias, and `sudo` doesn’t know about it. When you switch users to become `root`, your interactive shell runs its startup scripts and sets up the relevant aliases.

Try running `alias ls` as `root`, not *via* `sudo`, to see the corresponding command.

The difference in the output for symbolic links seems to be a side-effect of adding colours to the output:

```
ls -lp --color=tty /
```

v.

```
ls -lp --color=never /
```

will show the same difference.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it, even though i really dont get why changing the colors would make a character disappear.

Comment: It might be a bug...

Comment: Aliases are typically implemented internally by the shell as just another environment variable (or local variable if you want to be more technically accurate), and then add in commands such as `ls` read some environment variables to control how they behave and display things, and you will likely find the answer in seeing how they are defined in each situation. Compare the output of `set` in a user bash shell, with the output of `sudo set`, and again with the output of `set` from a root bash shell.

Comment: @C.M. in bash, [aliases are handled separately](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/alias.c). `sudo`’s environment processing has nothing to do with the behaviour seen here; `bash --norc` will show the same behaviour.